# Dynamically align item with CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to align a div in the parent container by allowing the user to select the following options:

- Top Left
- Top Middle
- Top Right
- Left Middle
- Centered
- Right Middle
- Bottom Left
- Bottom Middle
- Bottom Right

While I find a lot of resources how to vertically and horizontally align using flexbox, I am wondering if somebody has created a simple collection of CSS-classes I could easily apply.

**Edit**:
The basic markup is very simple, just a button:

```
<div>
    <div class="btn">This is my button</div>
</div>
```

Now to get to "Right Middle" I'd ideally to do something like:

```
<div class="vertical-align-middle horizontal-align-right">
   <div class="btn">This is my button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The CSS will depend on the HTML mark-up, specifically, the other elements within the parent container.  Can you provide a snippet of what the HTML may look like?

Comment: Added a basic example.

Comment: Are you specifying a height to the parent container? (Otherwise, the parent container will have a height determine by the `div.btn` element.)

Comment: `display: flex;` should do that.

Comment: @MarcAudet: Yes, the parent container has a height, but defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my example, you need to create classes for every position, then use a little jQuery to make it changed dynamically.

```js
(function() {
  $(".select-box").on("change", function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    $("#content").removeClass().addClass($selected);
  });
})();
```

```css
.select-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
#content {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

#content.top-left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#content.top-middle {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#content.top-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#content.left-middle {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
#content.centered {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#content.right-middle {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
#content.bottom-left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
#content.bottom-middle {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
#content.bottom-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<select class="select-box">
  <option value="top-left">Top Left</option>
  <option value="top-middle">Top Middle</option>
  <option value="top-right">Top Right</option>
  <option value="left-middle">Left Middle</option>
  <option value="centered">Centered</option>
  <option value="right-middle">Right Middle</option>
  <option value="bottom-left">Bottom Left</option>
  <option value="bottom-middle">Bottom Middle</option>
  <option value="bottom-right">Bottom Right</option>
</select>
```

Comment: These classes are all dependent on the flex direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can position elements in this way by creating one `container` element  with 3 sub-containers for each row with following css.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
```

This will position rows at top, middle and bottom of container. Next you can can use this css for each row and that will position divs at left, center and right of row.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="top row">
    <div class="box">Top left</div>
    <div class="box">Top center</div>
    <div class="box">Top right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle row">
    <div class="box">Middle left</div>
    <div class="box">Middle center</div>
    <div class="box">Middle right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom row">
    <div class="box">Bottom left</div>
    <div class="box">Bottom center</div>
    <div class="box">Bottom right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have single element in container then you can use different combinations of `align-items` and `justify-content` to position element but that also depends on `flex-direction` (by default is row). So for example if you want to position element at bottom-center you can use

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="btn">Button</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [morass](https://github.com/rtm/morass) library might be useful.

```
$ mkdir test-project
$ npm init
$ npm install morass
$ edit index.html
$ serve
```

where index.html is:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      .big { height: 200px; width: 200px; outline: 1px red solid; }
      .small { height: 100px; width: 100px; outline: 1px green solid; }
    </style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./node_modules/morass/dist/index.css'/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='big flex align-left align-bottom'>
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      <div class='small'></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

You can replace `align-left` with `align-center` or `align-right`, and `align-bottom` with `align-middle` or `align-top`, etc.

This morass library is based on what are called "micro-classes". For instance, you could also add a `vertical` class to make the flex items go top to bottom, or for multiple items, `justify` to spread them out.